# Linking a Session to a user - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm currently trying to find the best - secure- method of linking a session which I have generated to a user on my database. At the moment when the user logs in with valid credentials they are generated a session with,

```
function sessionStart(){
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
    ini_set('session.entropy_file', '/dev/urandom'); // better session id's, more random than PHP's default.
    ini_set('session.entropy_length', '512'); // How many bytes which will be read from the above file. 512 = overkill?
    ini_set('session.hash_function','sha512');
    ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character','6');
    $session_name = 'sec_login'; // Sets a custom session name.
    $secure = false; // Set to true if HTTPS is being used.
    $httponly = true; // Stops Javascript from being able to read the cookies.

    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
    session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}
```

This in theory generates a unique, secure id which can be used to identify a user. My only problem is how would I link the generated session to a user?

I'd assume that the best way would be to create a database table with two column (userId and SessionId) which is filled with the appropriate userIds and sessionIds when the session is created and updated when the user reloads different pages or deleted when the user logs out.

- Is this secure?
- Is there a better way of doing this?
- I noticed one method someone used was including a hashed + salted password in a cookie although this seemed extremely flawed to me hence why I'm not using it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review request. This is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to stackoverflow. Apologies again and thanks for the info. :)

Comment: I think youre on the right track with the database idea for the linking of the sessions. I'm not a security expert so I can't comment on your secure approach, but its seems sound and the database aspect will give you the user/session tie you need